# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression React JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, error-handling, jsx

I'm trying to make a if statement inside the style , but I keep getting the error `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression` inside the style if statements. I tried to fix putting `/* eslint-disable */` but the error changes to `` The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX. ``. Can somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function Calendar() {

return(
        <div>
            <table id='calendario'>
              <tbody>
                {lines.map((linha) => (
                  <tr key={linha}>
                  {columns.map((coluna , e , i) => (
                  <td
                  key={coluna} onLoad={() => {
                    e < index.length ? (e = e) : e++;
                    i >= proximo_mes.length ? (i = i) : i++;
                  }}
                  style={() => {linha == 0 && coluna == e ? {filter:"brightness(0.6)"} : {filter:"brightness(1)"};
                  linha == 4 && coluna == i ? {filter:"brightness(0.6)"} : {filter:"brightness(1)"}}}
                >{dias_no_mes[indice++]}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the style prop value should be something like the following since is expecting a value

```
<td
  ...
  style={{ filter: linha == 0 && coluna == e ? "brightness(0.6)" : "brightness(1)" }}
>
```

Comment: I changed but now im getting the following : The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.

Comment: I tried to do with just some one exprexpetion and it worked , but i need two expression inside the style

Comment: its showing the error : Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression . But when its just one expression its works , but I need the two expressions inside the style tag

Comment: I mean the code that you mentioned that works

Comment: style={linha == 0 && coluna == e ? {filter:"brightness(0.6)"} : {filter:"brightness(1)"}}